# Fundamental group of logarithmic surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

I am trying to determine the fundamental group of the following parametrized surface:
$$ X(r,\theta) = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta, ln(r^2)),$$
where $r\in(0,+\infty)$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. It can be thought of as the surface obtained when revolving the one-variable logarithm around the z-axis. Here's my problem.

On the one hand, I think that this surface is homeomorphic to the punctured plane. **Hence, its fundamental group should be $\mathbb{Z}$.**

On the other hand, I have come up with an apparently convincing proof that the one-variable logarithm is a strong deformation retract of this surface. Since the one-variable logartihm is just a line, it is homeomorphic to the real line $\mathbb{R}$. **Hence, the fundamental group should be trivial.**

**This is indeed a contradiction.** And I cannot seem to find the mistake I am making. Now I will include the strong deformation retract that I have come up with, which is likely to be mistaken. I claim $R$ is a retract of $X$:

$$ R = \{ (r,0,\log(r^2)) \,|\, r \in (0,+\infty) \} $$
$$ H: X \times [0,1] \longrightarrow X$$
$$ H( X(r,\theta) , t ) = ( r\cos(1-t) \theta , r \sin(1-t)\theta , \log(r^2)).$$

It seems to satisfy the conditions of a strong deformation retract, namely $ H(p,0)=p \,\,\forall \,\,p \in X $, $ H(p,t)=p \,\,\forall p \,\, \in R $ and $ H(p,1)\in R \,\,\forall \,\,p \in X $. Here's a picture of X (blue) and R (black):

[image]

Comment: is it possible to apply Van Kampen's Theorem?

Comment: It might be possible, but I don't see an easy way to do it.  Do you have any suggestion or hint? I would really appreciate it. Since X is quite a simple surface, I thought it might be possible to approach the problem without using such a powerful tool as Van Kampen's Theorem. @GopalAnantharaman

Comment: It's been a while. I have also have used it for simple 'Picturized' surfaces to prove Isomorphisms when I took the Course. Maybe you can refer to Hatcher's book..

Comment: What do you mean by one variable logarithm? What is X, the surface at the start? What is R?

Comment: By one-variable logarithm I mean f(x) = log(x), taking $x=r^2$ in our context. Yes, X is the surface at the start. R is the surface at the start, evaluated at $\theta = 0$. It looks like the one variable logartihm if you were to plot in the zx-plane (i.e. y=0 plane). @JoshuaTilley

Comment: I have added a GeoGebra picture to make things clear @JoshuaTilley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach is correct. This surface is homeomorphic to the punctured plane (by projection on the first two coordinates, for example). Your $H$ is not a continuous map on the surface $X$. This is because the map $X(r,\theta)\mapsto(r,\theta)$ is not continuous, even though it is bijective. For example, the sequence $(X(1,2\pi-1/n))_n$ converges to $X(1,0)$, but $(\cos((1-t)(2\pi-1/n)),\sin((1-t)(2\pi-1/n)),0)\rightarrow(\cos(2\pi(1-t)),\sin(2\pi(1-t)),0)$ and this does not equal $(1,0,0)$ for $0<t<1$.

Comment: Since $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $t\in[0,1]$, I don't see the problem. Could you explain it in more detail, please?

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Thorgott's answer, there is a well-defined map which sends points with *principal angle* $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ to points with principal angle $(1-t)\theta$ but this map is not continuous. You can see this since there is a 'cut' needed on the surface where nearby points are moved apart no matter how close they are. E.g. the angles $0$ and $2\pi-\varepsilon$.